# Installing Google Cloud SDK on Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform

I need to install https://cloud.google.com/sdk/ on my Azure Web App so we can execute `> gcloud auth application-default login`and have our application running with communication between Google and Azure.

How can I install https://cloud.google.com/sdk/ to the Azure Web App container? been looking for a command configuration (as in linux) but can't seem to find any info.